# Converting FORTRAN loop to Java

Tags: java, loops, fortran

For an assignment I've been given some stuff to do involving FORTRAN code, but the only issue is that we haven't been taught it yet so I'm not entirely sure what's going on so I've attempted to convert it to Java to try get a grasp on it. The following is the FORTRAN code:

```
L1:        DO 20 I = 1, 512
L2:           SUM(I) = 0
L3:           DO 40 J = 1, I
L4: 40         SUM(I) = SUM(I) + 1
L5: 20      CONTINUE
```

The idea is that L2 and L4 both take a machine cycle and I have to work out how long it takes for the loop to complete. The following is my Java which I think is at least reasonably close to working out the value I want:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int cycles = 0;
    for(int i = 1; i < 512; i++){
        cycles = cycles + 1;
        for(int j = 1; j < i; j++){
            cycles = cycles +1;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(cycles);
}
```

Does this seem correct? Any help is appreciated. I've thought through it mathematically and got a different answer (although both are close to each other) so I'm not sure which is better.

**EDIT:** I'd like to make clear that I'm not attempting to port the FORTRAN directly to Java, rather just calculate the cycle time mentioned above by using Java.

**EDIT 2:** I'm not trying to create the Array, only calculate the cycles taken during the loops. Because both lines L2 and L4 take a cycle, I've swapped it in the Java ONLY to figure out the cycles taken, not do what the FORTRAN loop does.

Comment: Your for statements should be "<=" not "<".  You're missing some cycles.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark ooops, made a typo - fixed it now. It was I + 1.

Comment: sum is an array. you have no array in your java....

Comment: @george This isn't the point, I'm trying to calculate the machine cycles not port the existing FORTRAN to Java. Therefore I don't need the Array, I only need to calculate the machine cycles taken when the loops have been run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Fortran the statement

```
DO 20 I = 1, 512
```

starts a loop whose end is the line with label `20`.  Similarly, the inner loop ends on the statement labelled `40`.  In modern Fortran this might look like

```
    DO I = 1, 512
       SUM(I) = 0
       DO J = 1, I
          SUM(I) = SUM(I) + 1
       END DO
    END DO
```

or even, since Fortran (since Fortran 90) has array statements and, as Duffymo has observed, `SUM` is an array

```
       DO I = 1, 512
          SUM(I) = I
       END DO
```

or, as I would write it, using an array constructor with an implied do loop:

```
SUM = [(I,I=1,512)]
```

The Fortran sets element `I`of `SUM` to `I`.

So, to answer OP's question more directly, the original Fortran code executes line 2 `512` times and line 4 `1+2+3+4+...+512` times.

My opinion is that writing a Java (or indeed any language) program to compute this sum is exactly the sort of thing that students of computer science (or software engineering or ...)  should be taught not to do; there is a well-known closed-form equation for the *sum of the first N integers* (italicised to clarify what the term you should be Googling for is) and any aspiring software developer ought to know this closed-form.  Such an aspirant ought to know this closed-form precisely to be able to figure out how many operations are invoked in loops such as the ones shown without having to write a program to iterate pointlessly.

To conclude, OP's Java program would get an `F-` on any course I taught because it is not an implementation of what ought to have been implemented - a function to calculate the sum of the first `N` integers. That `F-` would be applied irrespective of the correctness or otherwise of the program.  Since I'm not a teacher that's not much of a threat, but I simply wouldn't hire anyone pretending to be a software engineer without this knowledge.

Comment: I did actually go with the extended section of your answer afterwards because I hadn't actually looked at the code enough to realise what was needed. The only reason I went with Java in the first place is because I figured it'd be easier to just create the loops to do it for me, rather than having to think it through (having never seen FORTRAN and the tutor's initial explanation of the problem was a bit confusing).